# Tailrec in factorial

Tags: kotlin, recursion

Here's the code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val number = 6
    val factorial = fact(number)
    println("Factorial of $number = $factorial")
}

tailrec fun fact(n: Int, temp: Int = 1): Int {
    return if (n == 1){
        temp
    } else {
        fact(n-1, temp*n)
    }
}
```

I've seen multiple tutorials but still don't understand what tailrec does exactly.

Comment: Basically, `tailrec` makes the compiler give an error if your code is not structured in a way that allows the compiler to make the tail recursion optimization when compiling it. With tail recursion, the function uses less memory and is not limited by the stack.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I was assuming that you had to put tailrec there to use tail recursion. Bugged.